# Can I use number as a column name in table of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

The code is

```
CREATE TABLE 7e11bdd4717ced2cd931f0942b897bb5(
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 book_id varchar(50),
 fordate varchar(50),
 fortime varchar(50),
 forperson varchar(50),
 booker_id varchar(50),
 1_1 int,
 3_2 int,
 4_6 int,
 2_10 int,
 booking_timestamp varchar(50)
```

);

The code is not executing.what is the problem? I also tried this way adding `` on the numbers,like

```
CREATE TABLE 7e11bdd4717ced2cd931f0942b897bb5(
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 book_id varchar(50),
 fordate varchar(50),
 fortime varchar(50),
 forperson varchar(50),
 booker_id varchar(50),
 `1_1` int,
 `3_2` int,
 `4_6` int,
 `2_10` int,
 booking_timestamp varchar(50)
```

);

Error reduced but not executed. [Interestingly,this code worked few days ago,but not working suddenly.]

Comment: Table names can't start with numbers too

Comment: 1st: table names cant start with a number' 2nd: column names should not start with a number; 3rd: dont use varchar for everything, `book_id` is probably an int, `fordate` a date(?), `fortime` a time(?), `booker_id` an int and `booking_timestamp` a timestamp!

Comment: You should be able to use double quotes like `CREATE TABLE "7e11bdd4717ced2cd931f0942b897bb5" (` if you are running in ANSI mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem* using numbers as column names.

There is a limitation on table names though, you are not allowed to have a table name start with a number, it may contain a number if you wish, but it can't start with one (no, not even if you escape the number)

*: in my opinion and probably the one that has to maintain your project whenever you're gone, you really shouldn't as it isn't descriptive, if I look at your code I don't get what column 1_1 is or what data it holds but that's another answer to another question

Answer (score 0):

From the documents: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

so you must quote it with backtick (`) like this`7e11bdd4717ced2cd931f0942b897bb5`,`1_1`.

```
SELECT `1_1` FROM `7e11bdd4717ced2cd931f0942b897bb5`
```